# SQL: datetime2 overflow in WHERE, but not in SELECT

Tags: mysql, overflow, where-clause, dateadd, datetime2

I've seen plenty of threads about datetime2 overflows when hitting the minimum date, but I don't have that in my data. Additionally, the `DATEADD` works fine in the `SELECT` statement, but not in the `WHERE` statement. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, -8, MyDate) as 'PST Date'
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE DATEADD(hour, -8, MyDate) between '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-01'
```

Which resolves to:

```
Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow.
```

This query works just fine if I take out the `DATEADD` from the `WHERE` statement, but then I'm getting an 8-hour shift in my results. Any idea why this is happening or what I can do to make the `WHERE` work properly? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some value that cause the error?

Comment: Are you asking for the actual date values from the column? I'm not sure which date is causing the error, but I've scanned the column and don't see any weird looking dates.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a5c9bc6dc009688739f5cb148d58d852

Comment: Could this be an issue with the type of SQL installed to the DB? I'm not much for the backend side of things, but I can check with the admin to find out what version we're running. Thanks!